# Devise login error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to access the login errors messages the same way as I access errors in signup. In my case, whether the user has already confirmed the email or not.

```
<% = F.error_notification %>
```

But in login, does not show any error.

Someone?

***UPDATE***

As Nitish Parkar said, in our login page, error messages are shown in `flash` messages.

Thank you!

Comment: In login, devise returns error messages in `flash`.

Answer (score 0):

Devise returns errors in a slightly annoying way that might not be compatible with the way you usually display errors in your templates. I end up assigning them in an overridden controller.

```
def create
   build_resource(sign_up_params)
   resource_saved = resource.save
   yield resource if block_given?
   if resource_saved
     if resource.active_for_authentication?
       set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
       sign_up(resource_name, resource)
       respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     else
       set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
       expire_data_after_sign_in!
       respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     end
   else
     clean_up_passwords resource
     @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
     if @validatable
       @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
     end
     #respond_with resource
     flash[:error] = resource.errors.full_messages
     redirect_to '/signup'
   end
 end


 <% if !flash.empty? %>
   <div class="alert alert-success lead">
     <% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
       <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
     <% end -%>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```